# Create a "Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>" in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, dictionary

I've recently started using WPF, and by doing so got introduced to XAML.

I was wondering if it's possible to create a `Dictionary< string, Dictionary< string, string>>` in XAML.

I know you can create a `Dictionary< TKey, TValue>` but, I can't seem to place the Dictionary as the TValue of the Dictionary.

Can anyone help me?

This is my Dictionary class.

```
public class DictionaryForXAML : MarkupExtension, IDictionary
{
    public Type KeyType { get; set; }
    public Type ValueType { get; set; }

    private IDictionary _dictionary;
    private IDictionary Dictionary
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dictionary == null)
            {
                var type = typeof(Dictionary<,>);
                var dictionaryType = type.MakeGenericType(KeyType, ValueType);
                _dictionary = (IDictionary)Activator.CreateInstance(dictionaryType);
            }
            return _dictionary;
        }
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Dictionary;
    }

    public void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        if (!KeyType.IsAssignableFrom(key.GetType()))
            key = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(KeyType).ConvertFrom(key);

        Dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    //Additional inherited methods not posted
}
}
```

And my XAML Window resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Class:DictionaryForXAML x:Key="ValueDic" KeyType="System:String" ValueType="System:String"/>
    <Class:DictionaryForXAML x:Key="RootDic" KeyType="System:String" ValueType="???"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if i understood your question the right but have you tried something like?

```
    <Class:DictionaryForXAML x:Key="RootDic" KeyType="system:String">
        <Class:DictionaryForXAML.ValueType>
            <Class:DictionaryForXAML KeyType="system:String" ValueType="system:String"/>
        </Class:DictionaryForXAML.ValueType>
    </Class:DictionaryForXAML>
```

---

EDIT:

I tried something else, is this suitable for you?

**XAML**

```
<wpfApplication3:RootDictionary x:Key="RootDic">
    <wpfApplication3:SubDictionary x:Key="RootNodeA">
        <system:String x:Key="SubNode1">Test info1</system:String>
        <system:String x:Key="SubNode11">Test info1.1</system:String>
    </wpfApplication3:SubDictionary>  
    <wpfApplication3:SubDictionary x:Key="RootNodeB">
        <system:String x:Key="SubNode2">Test info2</system:String>
    </wpfApplication3:SubDictionary>
</wpfApplication3:RootDictionary>
```

**Code**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class RootDictionary : Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>>
    {

    }

    public class SubDictionary : Dictionary<string, string>
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, hadn't tried that.
Would it be possible to show me an example where you place <"RootNodeA", <"SubNode1", "Test info">> into the structure you showed me? Having trouble figuring it out :(

Comment: Thank you.
It was exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can just define from the begining the nature of your Dictionary:

```
Dictionary< string, Dictionary< string, string>> myDict=new Dictionary< string, Dictionary< string, string>>();

public void Add(string s, Dictionary< string, string> Dict)
{
    if (!myDict.ContainsKey(s))
    {
        myDict.Add(s,Dict)
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer explain how to declare the dictionary in **XAML**?

Comment: I say that he can alternatively declare it in xaml.cs...Just a thought maybe OP isnt looking for this..